# Pymodbus TCP Slave Busy

Tags: tcp, modbus, master-slave, pymodbus

I've been trying to update someone else' software to work on a new machine. 
They built a Modbus controller using the Pymodbus library to work with the main software.

The only difference between the original working machine and this new one is that the DAQ is different. 
I had assumed going in that this would just mean changing addresses but probably due to my lack of knowledge about Pymodbus this has been very far from the case.

The main issue I am having right now is that is that I am trying to simply communicate with holding registers and the only response I can get back is "(131, 3, Slave Device Busy)".
I am really not sure what to do with this information, It happens as soon as it is started and nothing is able to change it.

Has anyone else had any experience where a device always outputting this same error code?
the DAQ I am using is a Aspar IO Slim Module MOD-ETH 
Any advice would be much appreciated. 
Thank you 
J

(I would attached the code here but it is quite long and I'm not sure a snippet would really help but do let me know if it would be helpful)

Short test code

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient as ModbusClient 
import logging 
logging.basicConfig() 
log = logging.getLogger() 
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) 

log.debug("Connecting to controller (IP=169.254.54.23, Port 502)")
client = ModbusClient('192.168.1.135', port=502)
59 #client = ModbusClient(method='ascii', port='/dev/pts/2', timeout=1) 
60 # client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port='/dev/ttyp0', timeout=1) 



client.connect()

log.debug("Connected to controller (IP=192.168.1.135, Port 502)")
log.debug("Reading Sump Oil Temperature")

rr = client.read_holding_registers(1021, 1, unit=1)
log.debug("Read Sump Oil Temperature")


if rr.function_code > 0x80:
    print( "Error has occured!\n" + str( rr.function_code ) + "\n" + str( rr.exception_code ) )
else:
    print( rr.getRegister(0) )

client.close()
```

Response:

```
DEBUG:root:Connecting to controller (IP=169.254.54.23, Port 502)
DEBUG:root:Connected to controller (IP=192.168.1.135, Port 502)
DEBUG:root:Reading Sump Oil Temperature
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Current transaction state - IDLE
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Running transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:SEND: 0x0 0x1 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x6 0x1 0x3 0x3 0xfd 0x0 0x1
DEBUG:pymodbus.client.sync:New Transaction state 'SENDING'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'SENDING' to 'WAITING FOR REPLY'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'WAITING FOR REPLY' to 'PROCESSING REPLY'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:RECV: 0x0 0x1 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x3 0x1 0x83 0x6
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.socket_framer:Processing: 0x0 0x1 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x3 0x1 0x83 0x6
DEBUG:pymodbus.factory:Factory Response[131]
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Adding transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Getting transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'PROCESSING REPLY' to 'TRANSACTION_COMPLETE'
DEBUG:root:Read Sump Oil Temperature
Error has occured!
131
6
```

Comment: The [MOD-ETH manual](http://www.aspar.com.pl/katalogi/ETH_en.pdf)  says "If the module does not get the access to the RS485 network, the
package is sent back with the error code 0x06 – Server Device Busy" so my guess is that you have a wiring issue.

Comment: Thank you for the response but from what I can tell that applies only to when using it in gateway configuration. I am currently using it as a device table and am able to read correctly form the RS485 network using its online tool.

Comment: In that case the issue could be with the query (perhaps a discrete input rather than a holding register? - the english manual is not clear) or the MOD-ETH itself. I doubt that pymodbus is the issue but you can rule it out by testing comms with [another application](https://www.modbusdriver.com/modpoll.html).